# Editor that supports embedded terminal cross platform?

Tags: python, terminal, ide, editor

I use Python a lot across different platforms and I find it very convenient to have a terminal embedded inside the text editor mainly for running Python interactively. I used Atom with the platformio-ide-terminal package for a while, but the terminal crashes a lot on Windows.

I also looked at Geany which offers an embedded terminal on Linux and Mac, but not on Windows.

Do you know of some other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend Visual Studio Code, it is an open source editor forked from Atom by Microsoft. It has been more stable in my experience than Atom and has an integrated terminal that I use every day. It also has plugins that allow for intelligence/autocompletion and other IDE-like operations.

In addition to that it has fantastic built in version control.

Here is a link to the GitHub page: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

And here is one to the main page for the app: https://code.visualstudio.com

Comment: But there isn't a Visual Studio distribution for Linux. Only Mac and Windows.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux
Visual Studio Code runs on Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you said Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Comment: No worries! It's a good clarifying point.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) and its [embedded terminal](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html).

Answer (score 1):

A combination that I, myself, use is [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/) and a plugin called [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL). That's an interactive Python shell. There is another plugin called [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) which I believe adds a terminal although I haven't used it yet.

Since you said you use it across different platforms, sublime text allows you to create a 'local' installation which contains all of its resources in 1 folder. This allows you to easily sync up your different OSes or devices.

Like editors such as Atom, there are so many plugins available to help workflow like Git/GitHub integration. I've even published [my own](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/AddToFile).

Plugins are downloaded through a program called [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io). Choose from a large list of plugins ranging from things like code linting, auto-completion, code snippets, side bar enhancements and as many as you can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Best IDEs for Python development are

- PyCharm
- Spyder
- Atom

You can also use Sublime text. It's also a good editor.

Comment: Visual Studio is also a good IDE.

Answer (score 1):

So far the best IDE IMO:

1. VScode
2. sublime
3. Atom